# How to save in database the data response by paypal in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, paypal

I am trying to save the data in database which is response by paypal.
Here is my try, I get the data from paypal response like this.

```
public function getDone(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('paymentId');
    $token = $request->get('token');
    $payer_id = $request->get('PayerID');

    $payment = PayPal::getById($id, $this->_apiContext);

    $paymentExecution = PayPal::PaymentExecution();

    $paymentExecution->setPayerId($payer_id);
    $executePayment = $payment->execute($paymentExecution, $this->_apiContext);


    print_r($executePayment);
}
```

the result is here

```
PayPal\Rest\ApiContext Object ( [requestId:PayPal\Rest\ApiContext:private] => 216056242044171493312944593 [credential:PayPal\Rest\ApiContext:private] => PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential Object ( [logger:PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential:private] => PayPal\Core\PayPalLoggingManager Object ( [loggerName:PayPal\Core\PayPalLoggingManager:private] => PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential [isLoggingEnabled:PayPal\Core\PayPalLoggingManager:private] => [loggingLevel:PayPal\Core\PayPalLoggingManager:private] => [loggerFile:PayPal\Core\PayPalLoggingManager:private] => ) [clientId:PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential:private] => AVFGCgHNihKu_MpwgbpDPuB9FO8Z5hdgGrEx1mZPhQoOs2vLzFf1Dv6qA2bN5Ja_qucPYkN0X5Hrz9ZE [clientSecret:PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential:private] => EBdP51X4tMAi9WYcgI1ue0TQLljyvDBxO1yQAFJn7X7z_GP7mAOMnAsDCsREotfEOCESD_D6Qp14plTy [accessToken:PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential:private] => A21AAG85CiMoJ6JFJfQIfSMdzPm1sbwy7AZcT1zyxNbfw2-WXms8hgALJK3uFJy9DfG3oVQTKrIEApTwvDoiXAp49SrIiBfmw [tokenExpiresIn:PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential:private] => 32315 [tokenCreateTime:PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential:private] => 1493312949 [cipher:PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential:private] => PayPal\Security\Cipher Object ( [secretKey:PayPal\Security\Cipher:private] => EBdP51X4tMAi9WYcgI1ue0TQLljyvDBxO1yQAFJn7X7z_GP7mAOMnAsDCsREotfEOCESD_D6Qp14plTy ) [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( ) ) )
```

I want to save in database and how i try to do it is here

```
public function getDone(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('paymentId');
    $token = $request->get('token');
    $payer_id = $request->get('PayerID');

    $payment = PayPal::getById($id, $this->_apiContext);

    $paymentExecution = PayPal::PaymentExecution();

    $paymentExecution->setPayerId($payer_id);
    $executePayment = $payment->execute($paymentExecution, $this->_apiContext);

      if($request->tx){
        if($payment=Payment::where('transaction_id',$request->tx)->first()){
            $payment_id=$payment->id;
        }else{
            $payment=new Payment;
            $payment->transaction_id=$request->email;
            $payment->transaction_id=$request->name;
            $payment->item_number=$request->item_number;
            $payment->transaction_id=$request->tx;
            $payment->currency_code=$request->cc;
            $payment->payment_status=$request->st;
            $payment->save();
            $payment_id=$payment->id;
        }
    return 'Pyament has been done and your payment id is : '.$payment_id;

    }else{
        return 'Payment has failed';
    }



}
```

The error is showing like

> Payment has failed

Here is my database which is trying to save in

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('item_number');
        $table->string('transaction_id');
        $table->string('currency_code');
        $table->string('payment_status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Where am i wrong in my codes, please guide me to save in database.
Please guide me. Thanks.